# NullPool or QueuePool for remote Postgres SQLalchemy connections?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

When my Database service restarts:

```
Postgres throws terminating connection due to administrator command SSL 
connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

Above error comes when i am using QueuePool as the poolClass in create_engine function,like this:

```
conn_engine = create_engine(connect_db, poolclass=QueuePool)
```

But when i use pollClass as "NullPool", even i restart the DB multiple times above error doesn't comes,

```
conn_engine = create_engine(connect_db, poolclass=NullPool)
```

So can i Use NullPool for production and what are the advantages of NullPool over QueuePool in Sqlalchemy?

Comment: You can, but you may suffer a performance penalty, since `NullPool` is "A Pool which does not pool connections.

Instead it literally opens and closes the underlying DB-API connection per each connection open/close."

Comment: A better question is: why are you restarting your DB so often that it becomes a problem? Also, I'm fairly certain that the queue pool should be able to clean up lost connections, if you return them to the pool.

Comment: The Problem With My QueuePool is when DB is not connected for a long time suppose for more than a day, then my Service doesn't respond and throws the "connection closed error". If QueuePool can handle this like auto reconnect, then i am happy to use QueuePool

Comment: @AjayRawat you may searching for 'pool_pre_ping' or 'pool_recycle': https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects